# Kotlin - How to convert Double to String in Kotlin without scientific notation?

Tags: java, android, kotlin, double, tostring

I want to set in text view full value of Double without scientific notation (Exponential), what is best approach?

I tried convert Double value using method toString() on it, but I still have scientific value.

```
tvDepth.text=depth.toString()
```

I entered value 123456789.123456789 and expect same value in textView, but instead I have:
1.23456789123456789E8.

I don't know how many decimal places I need, so I couldn't format it before set it in text view. I read that in Java is available static method

```java
Double.toString(Double d)
```

but it's not available in Kotlin. Is there any good approach to show this value correctly?

Answer (score 22):

You can use `.toBigDecimal().toPlainString()` on your `Double`. For example:

```kotlin
println(PI.toBigDecimal().toPlainString())
```

prints out:

```
3.141592653589793
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try with this

```
  val dou = 123456789.123456789
  val df = DecimalFormat("0", DecimalFormatSymbols.getInstance(Locale.ENGLISH))
  df.maximumFractionDigits = 340 // 340 = DecimalFormat.DOUBLE_FRACTION_DIGITS
  val stringValue = df.format(dou)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
new BigDecimal("123456789.123456789").toPlainString();
```

This needs a bit of explanation. Floating point, `double`, has no notion of the number of decimals used; it always is an approximation, a sum of powers of 2.
`BigDecimal` is fixed point. Hence a constructor with a String must be used to have specify the precision.

And `toPlainString` avoids the scientific E-Notation.

Answer (score 1):

`"${x.toLong()}${(x%1).toString().drop(1)}".take(16)`

will do the trick. Didn't find a cleaner method but I didn't look that hard as I found something that works :)

Also, a double will hold only 15-16 digits, so you will end up getting pretty random digits at the end if you make the string larger.

Also, you can always make a nice extension function of it!

`fun Double.toMyString(): String = "${this.toLong()}${(this%1).toString().drop(1)}".take(16)`

then just 
`someLongNumber.toMyString()` to keep your code readable!

Comment: Good thing about this solution is that it works in kotlin multiplatform code.

Answer (score 1):

I tried a lot of different approaches, but all of them had flaws. In the end I came up with this:

```
fun Double.toDecimalNotationString() =
    String.format("%.99f", this) //convert number to string with 99 decimal places
        .trimEnd('0') //remove trailing zeroes
```

Input:

```
val numbers = listOf(12300.0, 123.0, 123.123, 0.00000000123, 0.000000000000000000123, 123.000000000123)
numbers.forEach { println(it.toDecimalNotationString()) }
```

Output:

```
12300.
123.
123.123
0.00000000123
0.000000000000000000123
123.000000000123
```